# Redirect to port when url is /:8080/

Tags: apache, .htaccess

So what I'm trying to do is create a new API on a port and I want to redirect `example.com/:8080/api/photo/35` (where 35 is dynamic) to `example.com:8080/api/photo/35` .

I have tried this code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/:8080/(.*)
RewriteRule /8080/(.*)/D /:8080\$1/D
```

but it doesn't seem to work.

I expect the example.com/:8080/api/photo/35 to rewrited to example.com:8080/api/photo/35

Comment: What's the difference in those URI? Redirect `X` to `X`?

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to httpd (apache) settings you can configure `RewriteLog` and `RewriteLogLevel` to see how apache is applying rules from .htaccess

But it seems that your RewriteRule has missing [R]edirect flag.
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html#old-to-new-extern

Another issue could be related to regex you used

```
RewriteRule    "^/:8080/(.*)$"  "https://example.com:8080/$1"  [R]
```

Ref.: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html#movehomedirs

Comment: Thanks for the comment, although I get the same error, my url is `http://vaybe.alicanyildiz.net/:8080/api/photo/35` and I want to redirect it to `http://vaybe.alicanyildiz.net:8080/api/photo/35` .